# What's the most efficient possible way to get the binary suffix of a number with GMP?

Tags: c, gmp

Equivalently I'd like to load `x % 2^n` into another mpz_t. It's not clear to me whether `mpz_mod` ([manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division#Integer-Division)) will be faster than something like:

```
mpz_t setSuffix(int n,mpz_t x){
  mpz_t y; 
  mpz_init_set_ui(y,0);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(mpz_tstbit(x,i)){
      mpz_setbit(y,i);
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

([bit manipulation functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling#Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling))

Can I do better here with some built in function, or is this the speed limit? It might be faster to run the loop backwards so allocation would only be done once.

Comment: Benchmark the different approaches and see?

Comment: Question is primarily if I'm missing some other method or built-in tool

Comment: Did you fail to notice the 2exp functions in the documentation on division?

Comment: @MarcGlisse that would readily get the prefix, but not the suffix if i'm not mistaken. I believe there would also be additional overhead in division rather than bit scanning.

Comment: You are mistaken, please re-read that page, division functions have several variants depending if you want the quotient, remainder, or both, and specific code for 2exp functions is implemented intelligently. And if you care about performance, you should try several versions and time them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate n/64, n%64.
2. Transfer (n/64) times 64-bit ints.
3. Transfer (n%64) bits individually.

Additional optimization (instead of 3. above):

4. Calculate (n%64)/32, (n%64)/16, (n%64)/8.
5. If any of those is bigger than 0 (i.e. is equal to 1), copy that amount of data in one pass.
6. Transfer the remaining (n%64)%8 bits individually.

It might still be faster that 4.-6. above if:

7. you calculate only (n%64)/8, (n%64)%8
8. transfer (n%64)/8 bytes
9. transfer (n%64)%8 bits

From here, do some benchmarking and improve as needed.

---

Note: I assumed you have a 64-bit system. For older systems, adjust as needed. Also, some of the math above might need some adjustments (in steps 4.-6.).

Comment: Edit: n as in the number of bits, not the initial value! I don't entirely follow this method, is the idea just to get handed a 64 bit int from the tail of the big int, rather than single bits, allowing for building the suffix quicker?

Comment: You understood me right, moving 64 bits at a time is definitely faster than moving 64 times single-bits. And yes, I understood that n is the number of bits :)  And speed is your main concern, when you mention "efficient", right?

Comment: Yes I do mean speed by efficiency. My confusion there is how to pull those 64 bit chunks from the big int (i.e. the only non-division method I've found is to query individual bits, and performing lots of divisions seems slow.)

Comment: I am not very familiar with the GMP library. In the worst case, you just access the low-level information - you will need to study the data structures / layout yourself. If I am not mistaken, there are low-level functions to help you with the task.

Comment: Just found that mpz_getlimbn returns the nth int used in the construction of the big int, so that should work!

Comment: Please share with us your final result, if it is working or not the way you expected.